# What happens when an array object is incremented in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

A very simple question, but I could not find the answer anywhere. Check the following code.

```js
var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

for(i=0; i < myArray.length; myArray++){
 console.log("Loop iteration step : "+i);
}

console.log("After array increment : " + myArray);
```

The `myArray++` is not a typo. As you can see, the code will only run once. And after running it once, the loop terminates and `myArray` becomes NaN.

What is happening here to the array? How can an array become a NaN?

P.S: OK, more information since everyone is curious why `myArray++` is not a typo. Yes, it was a typo at first. That's how I came up with this But that's not the problem I have here. I added the complete loop because I wanted to show the place I came up with this error.

Comment: You may read on type conversions: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: Seriously `myArray++` is not a typo? So you *do* want to `myArray++` and then you are wondering why it runs only once? :D Maybe you could then explain what you would like this code to do?

Comment: i++ instead of myArray++ why?

Comment: What do you mean by "`myArray++` is not a typo?" What else could it be? It doesn't do anything useful, as you can see.

Comment: It's not a typo in the context of this question. Yes, in the real world, if I wanted to iterate the array, it's a typo.

Comment: You don't need the loop to demonstrate the problem. Just `myArray = [1, 2, 3]; myArray++; console.log(myArray);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I have fixed some (shameful) misconception in terms of what the increment operand does. I fell into the same mistake of not looking up the actual docs. I hope this helps other users not fall upon the same mistake. (thank you for pointing that out @gurvinder372.)

I highly recommend you look up the documentation for "[Increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)" , the first sentence explains what's happening:

> The increment operator increments (adds one to) its operand and returns a value.

One would think the `Increment operator ++`behaves as following:

`myArray++` ---> `myArray = myArray + 1`;

When JavaScript evaluates `myArray + 1` anything can come off that. In this case just try it out:

```
var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
myArray + 1
"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,91"
```

You could assume then it assigns a `string` back to `myArray` , when `increment operator` in the `for loop` evaluates, it determines that value is not a number, hence the `NaN`, and `for loop` exits before second iteration when condition `i<NaN`evaluates to `false`. Try it out:

```
var a = "a";
a++;
NaN
```

But **that's not entirely correct** (I messed up in terms of what `myArray++` actually does under the hood, and it's better to understand what it's actually happening). Looking at the actual specs for [Postfix Increment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-postfix-increment-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) operator, we get the following:

**Steps**

`myArray++`

1. *lhs* = `myArray`
2. *oldValue* = `Number(myArray)`

   *oldValue* = **NaN**
3. *newValue* = `oldValue` + 1

   *newValue* = `NaN` +  1

   *newValue* = `NaN`
4. `myArray = NaN`
5. The `Postfix Increment` operator returns **oldValue**, `NaN` and now `myArray=NaN`

So what you end up with in your `for loop` after the first iteration when the `Postfix Increment` operator runs is:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
    statement

for ([initialization]; i<myArray.length; NaN)
    statement

for ([initialization]; i<NaN.length; NaN)
    statement

for ([initialization]; i<undefined; NaN)
    statement

for ([initialization]; false; NaN)
    statement
```

I hope this helps clear up a bit what's happening in every step and part of the loop and why `myArray` ends up with value `NaN`.

Here's something interesting to try and see if you understand why in this **infinite** loop your `myArray`gets to stay as `[...]` but `counter` is `NaN` after second call.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
var counter = myArray;
for(let i=0; i<myArray.length; counter++){
    console.log("Infinite calls. Never leaving and counter is " + counter);
   // i++; if you don't want to eat up that infinite loop.
}
```

**Answer**

You get the infinite loops because your expression `i<myArray.length` will always evaluate to `True` since `i` is never modified. Meanwhile, `counter` will go to `NaN`after first iteration because of what was explained at the start of the post. `myArray` stays cool because the `Postfix Increment` is done upon `counter`. 
Why does this loop iterate but the one you did, does not? Because in the one you did you end up changing the value of `myArray`into `NaN`forcing the expression in the loop `i<NaN.length`---> `i<undefined` to be `false` after first iteration, causing the loop to exit.

Comment: *myArray++ is actually myArray = myArray + 1;* No

Comment: The `for` loop won't change `"0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,91"` to `NaN`. The increment operator itself is doing that, it doesn't do concatenation.

Comment: Yes, the increment operator itself is doing that.. then just compares `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,91` < `10(myArray.length)` which returns `false`. So `for` loop will finished.

Comment: Thank you for going in to the extent of explaining why the for loop stop fro after a single iteration as well. That part I understood before  posting the question, my curiosity was regarding an array being a `NaN`. It's solved now.

Answer (score 4):

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-postfix-increment-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) for **Postfix Increment Operator**

> 2. Let oldValue be ToNumber(GetValue(lhs)).

And

```
var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
Number(myArray) //NaN
```

Hence `myArray++` => **NaN**

**Demo**

```js
var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log( "Just increment using postfix operator ", myArray++ );

myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log( "Number conversion ", Number(myArray) );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `++` and if the variable is not of type number, it will be converted to string using `toString` and then converted to number.

`Object.toString` returns `[object Object]`, so `Number('[object Object]')` returns `NaN`

Also when you do `++` is a short hand for `+=` so `myArray++` is equal to `myArray = myArray + 1;`. Now that your `myArray` is not an array, it does not have property length and it returns `undefined` (*as everything in JS is an object*) and the loop breaks.

---

As rightly pointed out by @[barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar), `Array.toString` returns `array.join`. So it is equal to `Number("0,1,2...")`. Since comma(`,`) is not a valid numeric character, it returns `NaN`. Also, when value is compared to `NaN`, it returns `false` hence breaking the loop.

**Sample:**

```js
var myArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
console.log(myArray.toString())
console.log(Number(myArray.toString()))
console.log(1<NaN)
```

Comment: `Array.toString` returns `this.join(',')`, i.e. `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"`, not `[object Object]`