# Iterate over arr and pass its values to cb one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to complete a challenge within JavaScript and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

The directions say this:
Iterate over arr and pass its values to cb one by one.

Hint: you will be invoking cb multiple times (once for each value in the array).

Do not use the built-in forEach method for this.  Use a regular for loop.

My code looks like this:

```
function forEach(arr, cb) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr += cb();
  }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why I can't get it to pass. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *Pass it* means passing the value as a parameter. `cb(arr[i])`

Comment: you call `cb()` ... so cb is receiving no arguments

Comment: Ok so I'm still confused. What exactly am I needing to pass to cb()?

Comment: Please note that `+=` replaces the value. So if you do `arr +=`, it will result in `NaN`. Refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223284/what-happens-when-an-array-object-is-incremented-in-javascript)** for more info.

Comment: @AdamAzad Thanks. That helped out a lot. I couldn't figure out what I needed to put within the parentheses to call. Thanks again so much.

Answer (score 4):

As described [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256918/iterate-over-arr-and-pass-its-values-to-cb-one-by-one#comment83496497_48256918), the value at each index of `arr` is supposed to be passed as an argument to `cb` ...

```
function forEach(arr, cb) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    cb(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Where are these challenges from?

Answer (score 3):

Yes [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256918/iterate-over-arr-and-pass-its-values-to-cb-one-by-one#comment83496497_48256918) is right, all you have to do is pass the array with the specific index. Here is some example code for you

```js
var exampleArray = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O', ' ', 'W', 'O', 'R', 'L', 'D']

function forEach(arr, cb) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    cb(arr[i]);
  }
}

function logMe(item) {
  console.log(item)
}

forEach(exampleArray, logMe)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same using `Array.prototype.map()`

simple exemple:

```
// let's setup the example firsthand
const myArray = ['a','b','c'];
function cb(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

// the actual example
myArray.map((item) => cb(item));
/*if you had openned your console you should see 'a', 'b' and 'c'
  being printed */
```

Comment: "Do not use the built-in forEach method for this. Use a regular for loop."

Comment: My bad I had missed that line, sorry for the inconvenience :(